# Does R have shorthand to generate a sequence of integers?

Tags: r, vector

Does R have shorthand, function or operator which I can use to easily generate the following vector?

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Something like

```
v1 <- 1..5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
> 1:5
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

or

```
> seq(1, 5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

`seq` is quite flexible, in that it allows you to specify the stride, the desired number of output elements, etc., in various combinations:

```
## Default S3 method:
seq(from = 1, to = 1, by = ((to - from)/(length.out - 1)),
    length.out = NULL, along.with = NULL, ...)
```

For example:

```
> seq(from=1, by=3, length.out=5)
[1]  1  4  7 10 13
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use:

```
v1 <- 1:5
```